# system format error when converting to decimals

Tags: c#, .net

error code at: `Decimal price = Decimal.Parse(txtprice.Text);`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal height1 = decimal.Parse(txtnorthheight.Text);

        decimal length1 = decimal.Parse(txtnorthlength.Text);

        decimal area1 = height1 * length1;

        lblnortharea.Text = area1.ToString("n");

        decimal height2 = decimal.Parse(txtsouthheight.Text);

        decimal length2 = decimal.Parse(txtsouthlength.Text);

        decimal area2 = height2 * length2;

        lblsoutharea.Text = area2.ToString("n");


        decimal height3 = decimal.Parse(txteasthheight.Text);

        decimal length3 = decimal.Parse(txteasthlength.Text);

        decimal area3 = height3 * length3;

        lbleastarea.Text = area3.ToString("n");


        decimal height4 = decimal.Parse(txtwesthheight.Text);

        decimal length4 = decimal.Parse(txtwestlength.Text);

        decimal area4 = height4 * length4;

        lblwestharea.Text = area4.ToString("n");


        decimal height5 = decimal.Parse(txtwinheight.Text);

        decimal length5 = decimal.Parse(txtwinlength.Text);

        decimal area5 = height5 * length5;

        lblwinharea.Text = area5.ToString("n");

        decimal areatotal = (area1 + area2 + area3 + area4) - area5;

        lbltotalarea.Text = areatotal.ToString("n");

        decimal Heightt = (height1 + height2 + height3 + height4) - height5;
        decimal Legntht = (length1 + length2 + length3 + length4) - length5;

        Height2.Text = Heightt.ToString("n");
        Legnth.Text = Legntht.ToString("n");

        Decimal price = Decimal.Parse(txtprice.Text);

        Decimal undercoat = Decimal.Parse(txtunder.Text);

        decimal roomcost = (Heightt * Legntht) * price * undercoat;

        txtprice.Text = roomcost.ToString("c");

        decimal Vattotal = (25 % roomcost);

        lblvat.Text = Vattotal.ToString("c");

        Decimal vt = Vattotal + roomcost;

        lblbt.Text = vt.ToString("c");
    }
```

the worked without issue but now that i am rebuilding the program due to some errors this line of code does not want to work. any ideas ?

if requested i can post the whole 269 lines of code and also the visual studio error code.

Comment: What's the value of `txtprice.Text`? Apparently something that's not a valid decimal string. Maybe there's whitespace before or after the text?

Comment: There are thousands of questions about error message you should be getting... If you want personalized help - make sure to carefully read [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post accordingly to show how your case is different from existing once.

Comment: What is the error message? Is this a compilation error or a runtime error? If it is a runtime error what value was txtprice.Text?

Answer (score 0):

[`Decimal.Parse(string s)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z(v=vs.110).aspx) throws a `FormatException` if the input string isn't in a format that can be parsed as a `decimal`.

You can use `Decimal.TryParse(string s, out Decimal d)` instead.

```
decimal d = 0;
if(Decimal.TryParse(txtnorthheight.Text, out d))
{
    // If the string could be parsed, d contains the value.
    // otherwise TryParse returns false.
}
```

In order for that to be manageable you'd probably want to break your function down into smaller pieces and parse your inputs first. Otherwise the logic gets messy if there are multiple points throughout the method where you might have to exit because of invalid inputs.

Another approach is to use validation to ensure that only values of certain types can be entered. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603(v=vs.110).aspx) is some documentation on Windows Forms validation. (I can't tell for sure if you're using Forms or ASP.NET.)

Comment: thank you i have now solved the issue. without making another post i have now came across a issue where im trying to enforce a range on inputs for example, inputs must be between 0.9 and 2.0. im unable to find a way to enforce this on inputs without spamming the user with .showmessages. is there a more simple way to do this ?

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms app?

Comment: yes it is, im writing everything in vs using windows forms.

Comment: It's been years since I worked with this, but I think this is what you're looking for. [http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-use-validation-in-windows-form-application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-use-validation-in-windows-form-application). It gives you a way to validate form fields and indicate all of the fields that need to be corrected at the same time instead of showing a series of messages for each one.